# Adding a package directory to MiKTeX on mac

Tags: miktex, mac

I was just given a macbook by my employer for work. I am mostly a windows person and I use MiKTeX (and TeXStudio) for my LaTeXing. I have a number of personal .sty files that I keep in my dropbox, so that they sync across all my devices, but I'm having trouble getting my new computer to find them.

I've added the folder in my dropbox to the list of directories in the MiKTeX console just like on my windows machines, and refreshed and updated everything, but when I try to compile a document that calls for the packages in my dropbox, the log says it is not found.

A basic hello world compiles fine. Any ideas on how to fix it?

**Update**

I think it is fixed now? It seems that either the PATH variable wasn't set correctly, or I needed to use the terminal to open MiKTeX console as an administrator. I'm not sure whether it was one or both, but the document complies now.

Comment: If it is as on Windows, you should launch MiKTeX Console (preferably in Administrator mode), click on the `Settings` button and select the `Directories` tab  to add a TeXMF (local) Root. You can install your files in this directory, respecting the TDS architecture.

Comment: @Bernard That is what I have done, except the administrator part as the option is greyed out.

Comment: A problem of administrator rights, maybe? On Windows the File menu of MiKTeX Console has the item `Switch to Administrator mode`.

Comment: @bernard that is the only difference I can see. On mac that option is greyed out.

Comment: And you don't have administrator rights on your Mac?

Comment: @Bernard I do, and I am login into the administrator account,

Comment: As I don't have a Mac, it's hard for me  to give anything else than a general help. Anyway, creating this local root with administrator mode is mainly to ensure anyone using your Mac will have access to the local root. If you're the only user, that's not so important after all…